# Compare VARIANT bstr to System::String^

Tags: .net, string, visual-c++, c++-cli, mixed-mode

I have a method that takes in a System::String^ and internally obtains a VARIANT. I want to compare the var.bstrVal with my string and it never seems to find a match even though I know it does. Here is the code (NOTE: I have updated this with more detail):

```
System::String^ filterName = "MyStringThatMatches";
//pass to method and code to build up the VARIANT called var...
IPropertyBag *pPropBag;
pMoniker->BindToStorage(0, 0, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pPropBag));
VARIANT var;
VariantInit(&var);
pPropBag->Read(L"FriendlyName", &var, 0);
pin_ptr<const wchar_t> convertedFilter = PtrToStringChars(filterName);
    if (0 == wcscmp(var2.bstrVal, convertedFilter))
```

So the wcscmp never finds a match. I thought I was on the right track here.. Any ideas?

Comment: what is wcsmp and  can you provide MCVE?

Comment: Side note: Use utf8 to get rid of stupid unicode encodings.

Comment: This particular example works just as expected ('wcscmp' returns 0). Maybe there is something wrong with the way you are initializing the VARIANT? Please post some more code.

Comment: wcscmp() is a pretty crude way to compare Unicode strings but isn't technically wrong.   Simply use the debugger, use Debug > Windows > Memory > Memory 1 and put "filterName" in the Address box.  Do it again, now using Memory 2 and use "var2.bstrVal".  Now you see what wcscmp() sees and it should be obvious how the strings could differ.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion to use the Memory windows Hans. It turns out my code was fine but the string I was comparing to had an extra whitespace in it.